# MySQL: Índice total stock de cada producto

Tags: mysql, index

Tengo tres tablas: **productos, socios y stocks** (tabla de relación de las dos anteriores), debo realizar un índice con `explain` que me devuelva el total de stock de cada producto, y no sé cómo construirlo:

```
create index idx_totalstock on stocks(stock);
explain select sum(stock) from stocks where match ... ¿?
```

La tabla es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE stocks (
    cod_tien    TINYINT         NOT NULL,
    cod_pro     TINYINT         NOT NULL,
    stock       INT         NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (cod_pro) REFERENCES productos (cod_pro) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (cod_tien) REFERENCES socios (cod_tien) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (cod_tien, cod_pro)
)engine= MyISAM;
```

Gracias de antemano y un cordial saludo.

Comment: que tal  podrias agregar mas informacion, como un mer o diagrama, al parecer necesitas hacer una relacion de m-m , (stock_pruducto), pero no estoy seguro, falta info

Comment: La relación está hecha:

CREATE TABLE productos (
    cod_pro     TINYINT      AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre   VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    categoria   VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    descripcion VARCHAR(400)    NOT NULL,
    precio_com  NUMERIC(7,2)    NOT NULL,
    precio_ven  NUMERIC(7,2)    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (cod_pro)
);

Esta es la otra tabla para realizar el índice.

Answer (score 0):

Para calcular el total de stock de cada producto lo que necesitas es un agrupamiento:

```
SELECT cod_pro,
  SUM(stock) total_producto
  FROM stocks
  GROUP BY 1;
```

Es decir, sumar el número de productos de cada tipo que hay en las diferentes tiendas.

Comment: Gracias David, efectivamente ese es el SELECT correcto pero necesitaba la creación del INDEX y su EXPLAIN, pero ya lo tengo.

Comment: Era el que ponías en la pregunta, ¿no?